# mail server OVH configuration

Tags: docker, mail-server, ovh

I'm trying to setup a mail server for the first time. I do think everything is fine on my server side. However it seems that my ovh configuration is a bit more painful.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml (for those who know docker-mailserver image)

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  mail:
    image: tvial/docker-mailserver:latest
    hostname: mail
    domainname: bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr
    container_name: mail
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "143:143"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
    volumes:
      - maildata:/var/mail
      - mailstate:/var/mail-state
      - ./config/:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
    environment:
      - ENABLE_SPAMASSASSIN=1
      - ENABLE_CLAMAV=1
      - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
      - ENABLE_POSTGREY=1
      - ONE_DIR=1
      - DMS_DEBUG=0
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_PTRACE

volumes:
  maildata:
    driver: local
  mailstate:
    driver: local
```

I do end up with this in my logs

`mail.bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr is up and running`

I also configured a user and dkim keys.

here is my config so far in ovh and I cant send emails.

[image]

I have these kinds of logs when trying to send an email from nodemailer

```
postfix/qmgr[955]: 6551946BAF: from=<amavis@mail.thibautduchene.fr>, size=762, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  2 04:53:36 mail postfix/smtp[31638]: connect to mail.thibautduchene.fr[213.186.33.20]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  2 04:53:36 mail postfix/smtp[31638]: 6551946BAF: to=<amavis@mail.thibautduchene.fr>, orig_to=<amavis>, relay=none, delay=113725, delays=113695/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.thibautduchene.fr[213.186.33.20]:25: Connection timed out)
```

that is why I think my ovh configuration default to the mail server on thibautduchene.fr. And I would like to use bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr which is another mail server.
How should I do that?
thanks

Comment: With a "connection timed out" error, combined with the fact that you are enabling CAP_NET_ADMIN, can you grab the output of `iptables-save` from inside the running container? Also, are you able to make any outgoing connections? Do you get the connection timed out to only _some_ mailservers? What about doing a curl on port 80?

Comment: I don't think the problem is that much technical, I'm totally a newbie, the configuration docker should work as is. However when sending a mail via smtp on port 585, I get those logs, which point to a mail server ovh setted up for me. but not on my docker mailserver. That is my first problem. Hence what is wrong with my ovh config so that I can point to my mailserver on my subdomain which would be: mail.bnbkeeper.thibautduchene instead of mail.thibautduchene.fr

Answer (score 0):

SMTP Server shall be reachable via standard ports:

```
TLS:587
SSL:465
No Encryption: 2525
IMAP (Receiving): 25
```

You can setup absolutely free email server via AWS free tier, just make sure you choose clean IP.
You can try to instal mailinabox free and open source software, on fresh Ubuntu 14.44 version. Or any other open source mail server would work just fine.